# In JQuery Mobile Phonegap, tab is not working if list item is under fixed footer (tabs) in Android

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery, footer

In JQuery Mobile + Phonegap, I have list of item in a screen with fixed footer having 4 button. When any list item is coming under footer while scrolling, and tapping on tag (a button in footer), tab event is not working, list (below to tab button) event is triggering.

This problem is coming after upgradation to Cordova.